How is interest taken into account when calculating personal income?
personal income = national income - social insurance contributions + transfers - corporate profits + dividends - net interest + personal interest income
I don't quite understand the movement of interest in this formula for calculating personal income.
To formulate the question I will introduce some notation: G - government, H - households, F - firms. G2F - interest payments that the government (G) pays to firms (F) on borrowed funds. G2H - interest payments that the government (G) pays to households (H), etc.
I want to know where the errors are in my formulas:

personal interest income = G2H + F2H + H2H
net interest = G2F + H2F + F2F - F2G - F2H - F2F
national income = (W + R + P) + (G2F + H2F + F2F)


H2H is an internal transfer within the household sector so does not represent net income to that sector as a whole.
